# ダブルクォーテーション内にカンマ入りのcsvファイルを出力したい

Tags: c#, csv, linq, datagridview

datagridviewに表示中のデータをcsvファイルとして出力する際にダブルクォーテーション内にカンマがある行のみズレてしまっています。当初読み込み時に処理すると思っていたのですが、書込み時に行う方が適切ということだったのですが、datagridview1に表示してあるデータをダブルクォーテーションで囲う方法がわかりませんでした。ので教えていただきたいです。

取り込み時csvの例

```
あ,あい,あ
あ,"あ,い",あ
```

出力時csvの例(この形に書き直したい)

```
"あ","あ","あ","あ","あ"
"あ,い","あ,い,う","い","う","え,あ"
```

読み込み時のコード

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(csvFilePath, encoding))
{
    //カンマ区切りのcsv形式にする
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };

    //最後まで繰り返す
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

        parser.TrimWhiteSpace = false;

        //フィールド作成
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
```

書込みコード

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(DESKTOP + "\\" +DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").Replace("/", string.Empty).Replace(":", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty)+".csv", false, Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis")))
{

    int i;
    int Columns = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
    int rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    List<string> strList;
    strList = new List<string>();

    for (int c = 0; c < Columns; c++)
    {
        strList.Add(dataGridView1.Columns[c].HeaderCell.FormattedValue.ToString());
    }
    //配列変換
    string[] strHeader = strList.ToArray();
    //csv変換

    string strCsvData2 = string.Join(",", strHeader);
    writer.WriteLine(strCsvData2);

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        strList = new List<string>();

        for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
        {
            strList.Add(dataGridView1[j, i].FormattedValue.ToString());
        }
        string[] strArray = strList.ToArray();
        string strCsvData = string.Join(",", strArray);

        writer.WriteLine(strCsvData);
    }

}
```

Comment: 「datagridviewに表示されているデータをダブルクォーテーションで囲う」のではなく、「csvファイル出力」の方を修正すべきなのではないですか?

Comment: @OOPer  ご返答ありがとうございます。出力時のコードがdatagridviewの内容をそのまま書き出しているはずなのですが、読み込み時よりも書き込み時にダブルクォーテーションを追加するほうが変更箇所少なくなりますかね。

Comment: 変更箇所が少なくなる、と言うよりかは、CSV出力というのはそう言うもんです、と言いたいところです。実際問題として変更箇所も少なくなるし処理全体の見通しも良くなると思います。

Comment: なるほど。そういうものなのですね。ご返答ありがとうございます。@OOPer

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるのでは？[DataTableや配列等をCSV形式のファイルとして保存する](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/file/writecsvfile.html)

Comment: 結局、どのような答えを求めているのかよくわかりません。「データごとに囲う」とは何ですか？ 加筆するのではなく、質問文を整理してください。

Comment: kunifさんのリンク先はなぜ適用できないのですか？

Comment: @v..snow  すみません適用できないという表現だと語弊が出たので修正致しました。プログラミング初心者で読解ができなかったという感じになります。dataTableや配列の知識が疎くわからなったのですが、当てはめて実行したところエラー解消ができず行き詰ってしまっている状況になります。

Comment: 値は常にダブルクォートで囲むべきだけど、`,`(カンマ) や `"`(ダブルクォート) などの制御文字を含まない場合は省略可能、という考え方のようです。[CSVファイルフォーマットの解説：CodeZine](https://codezine.jp/article/detail/2364)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[参考ページ](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/file/writecsvfile.html) のコメント文にもある通り、`EncloseDoubleQuotesIfNeed`は '必要ならば、文字列をダブルクォートで囲む' 処理です。
引数に元文字列を取り、返り値として（必要ならば）囲んだ結果を返します。

一方質問文提示コードでは

```
        for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
        {
            strList.Add(dataGridView1[j, i].FormattedValue.ToString());
//                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 一要素に格納したい文字列
        }
        string[] strArray = strList.ToArray();
        string strCsvData = string.Join(",", strArray); // , で連結
```

の部分でcsvの行に変換しているので、一要素に格納したい文字列格納したい文字列を変換関数に渡せばよいはずです。

```
        for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
        {
            string item = dataGridView1[j, i].FormattedValue.ToString(); // あ,い
            string convertedItem = EncloseDoubleQuotesIfNeed(item);      // "あ,い"
            strList.Add(convertedItem);
        }
        string[] strArray = strList.ToArray();
        string strCsvData = string.Join(",", strArray); // あ,"あ,い",あ
```

---

質問文だとすべての要素を囲みたい、という風になっていますが、この変換関数は必要なものだけを囲みます。
すべて囲むには`string convertedItem = EncloseDoubleQuotesIfNeed(item);`の部分を調整してください

Comment: まあ必ず`"`を付加したいなら、`IfNeed`の付かない`EncloseDoubleQuotes()`を直接使えば良いでしょうね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事問題解決できました。こういうものって習得するためにどういう順番で学習するのがいいのでしょうか？学校で全く違う分野を学んでいてプログラミングを学んでいるわけではなくネットで検索、質問したタイミングで新しい言葉が出てきて形を覚えている状態なのですが、おすすめの教材とかありますでしょうか？

Comment: その手の質問は避けるべきリストにのってた気もしますが一応答えると、私のおすすめは大手書店に行き、C#のコーナーの入門書を適当に選ぶことです。リアル店舗のおすすめならば大外れはないはずです。